# Good and simple image editing program for Android?

Tags: android, images

Can you recommend me one? I'd like basic functionality cropping, rotating, saving.

Comment: I'm not using such on Android myself (so I cannot really *recommend*), but until answers start popping up here, you might wish to take a look at my list of [Photo Editing Apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Niklas Rtz, for what you describe, you most likely already have installed.  If not, it's free anyway.

I just use the Google+ Photo editor that's already on my device, and it has everything you mentioned:

[image]

You can read more about it [here](http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/02/26/google-android-gets-photo-editing-across-devices-one-view-photos-new-filters-creative-tools/) and can download it (if needed) [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus).  It's icon will look like this:  [image]

If you don't want to use that particular tool, then check out [PicsPlay Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jellybus.fx&hl=en) which isn't free, but very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Pixlr: https://pixlr.com/mobile
[image: Pixlr Autodesk for Android]

More options can be found here: https://alternativeto.net/software/pixlr/?platform=android